# Active highpass filter design?

Tags: filter, frequency, active-filter, high-pass-filter

How can I design an active highpass filter with |T(0)|=0.1 and |T(inf)|=1 and one critical frequency (either a pole or a zero) at 200 Hz?

Comment: It's part of an assignment, so just a simple and straightforward solution. Don't know how to tackle this.

Comment: Homework problems are off-topic here unless accompanied by an adequate attempt to solve. I'm sure that with a bit of reading in your textbook and a few online searches, you can cobble together the start of a solution, at least.

Comment: At first, it is necessary to become familiar with the SPECIFICATION for filters (gain, damping requirements, order and approximation method of the filter, passband requirements,...).

Comment: Ah, understood. Thanks. I did a bit of research. Can someone tell me what the T(0) specifies (what T is called and what it signifies)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that T(0) means the DC gain of the circuit, although H(0) is more common...

In any case, if you need an active filter, what does that mean?  Typically an op amp.

How about a simple inverting amp?  Some impedance in series with the negative input and some impedance between that negative input and the output, right?  And ground the positive input through some simple resistor.

The transfer function of a simple inverting op amp is \$-\frac{Z_{feedback}}{Z_{series}}\$

So for DC, gain is 0.1, so the series (to the inverting input) impedance should be 10 times larger than the feedback impedance.  So Z_series could be 10 kohm and Z_feedback could be 1 kohm.

But we also need higher gain for high frequency.  So, we can decrease series impedance by putting a capacitor in parallel with the series resistor, correct?  This gives us higher gain at higher frequency without changing DC gain.

How much capacitance?  Use the following equations:

\$T(\omega)=-\frac{Z_{feedback}}{Z_{series}}\$

\$Z_{feedback}=R_{feedback}=1,000 \Omega\$

\$Z_{series}=\frac{1}{j\cdot \omega\cdot C+\frac{1}{R_{series}}}=\frac{1}{j\cdot \omega\cdot C+\frac{1}{10,000}}\$

for the pole at 200 Hz

\$\omega=2 \cdot \pi \cdot f = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 200\$

\$|T(2 \pi 200)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}\$